# How to lock Java threads so that it locks out others until Platform.runLater has finished

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

In my OSGi based application bundles can be started and stopped at any time. The UI facing bundles register a javafx Node with the 'desktop' bundle. Manipulating the UI must be done on the JavaFX UI thread using `Platform.runLater()`, which will schedule it for execution at a later time.

I would like to make sure that only one caller can modify the desktop at a time. I used a lock and a condition to achieve this.

```
public class DesktopContent implements ContentManager {
  private final Pane desktop;
  private final AtomicReference<Node> weather = new AtomicReference<>();
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  @Override
  public void setWeatherWidget(Node node) {
    updateFX(() -> replaceNode(desktop.getChildren(), weather, node));
  }

  private void updateFX(Runnable runnable) {
    lock.lock();
    Condition condition = lock.newCondition();
    try {
        if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
            runnable.run();
        } else {
            updateFX(runnable, condition);
            condition.await();
        } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "While waiting for 'updating' condition", e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  private void updateFX(Runnable runnable, Condition condition) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } finally {
            condition.signal();
            lock.unlock();
        }
    });
}

private void replaceNode(List<Node> children, AtomicReference<Node> current, Node newNode) {
    SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition();
    ObservableList<Animation> transformations = st.getChildren();
    Node oldNode = current.getAndSet(newNode);

    if (oldNode != null) {
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(350), oldNode);
        ft.setToValue(0d);
        ft.setOnFinished(e -> children.remove(oldNode));
        transformations.add(ft);
    }

    if (newNode != null) {
        newNode.setLayoutX(100d);
        newNode.setLayoutY(100d);
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(350), newNode);
        ft.setFromValue(0d);
        ft.setToValue(1d);
        children.add(newNode);
        transformations.add(ft);
    }

    st.play();

}
```

}

I'm not sure this is right. If the caller is not on the application thread, the framework will schedule the execution of the runnable, and the caller will wait until the condition is met.

But if in the meantime somebody else would call setWeatherWidget I assume it will happily be granted the lock, scheduling another `runLater`. This means I could just as well skip any locking at all.

How should this be properly handled using locks? Introduce yet another 'global' lock? Or is this over-engineering and all this locking business is unnecessary?

Comment: I usually use `CountDownLatch` instead of conditions as it avoids one race: `signal()` could be called earlier than `await()`. That aside, I don't exactly get what you're trying to achieve. Runnables are executed in one thread, and therefore can't be executed concurrently, thus guaranteeing that “only one caller can modify the desktop at a time” without any locking.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov There is no possibility of `signal()` being called before `await()`.  The first updateFX method is already holding the lock when the runLater is executed, so the runLater cannot obtain the lock unless and until the first method executes `await()`.  (But using CountDownLatch would make the code shorter.)

Comment: @VGR, you're right. I stand corrected. I have seen this kind of race with `Object.wait` much too often and became over-cautious. Still, one more thing about `await()`: it allows spurious wakeups. `CountDownLatch` doesn't (at least according to the docs).

Comment: All your lock is doing is effectively blocking until the runnable submitted to `Platform.runLater(...)` completes. You can achieve the same by wrapping the runnable in a `FutureTask` and calling `get()` after submitting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this without getting into lower-level details with locks, conditions, etc. Essentially you want to make all calls to `setWeatherWidget` single-threaded (only one can be called at once), while of course making sure that code that must be performed on the FX Application Thread is done so. The point is that the FX Application Thread is already a single thread: so you can achieve this by sending requests to the FX Application Thread and blocking until those requests are complete:

```
public class DesktopContent implements ContentManager {
    private final Pane desktop;
    private final AtomicReference<Node> weather = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public void setWeatherWidget(Node node) {
        updateFX(() -> replaceNode(desktop.getChildren(), weather, node));
    }

    private void updateFX(Runnable runnable) {
        try {
            if (Platform.isFxApplicationThread()) {
                runnable.run();
            } else {
                FutureTask<Void> task = new FutureTask<>(runnable, null);
                Platform.runLater(task);
                // block until task completes:
                task.get();
            } 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "While waiting for 'updating' condition", e);
        }
    }

    private void replaceNode(List<Node> children, AtomicReference<Node> current, Node newNode) {
        SequentialTransition st = new SequentialTransition();
        ObservableList<Animation> transformations = st.getChildren();
        Node oldNode = current.getAndSet(newNode);

        if (oldNode != null) {
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(350), oldNode);
            ft.setToValue(0d);
            ft.setOnFinished(e -> children.remove(oldNode));
            transformations.add(ft);
        }

        if (newNode != null) {
            newNode.setLayoutX(100d);
            newNode.setLayoutY(100d);
            FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(350), newNode);
            ft.setFromValue(0d);
            ft.setToValue(1d);
            children.add(newNode);
            transformations.add(ft);
        }

        st.play();

    }

}
```

Comment: This solution seems much easier than my complex one. I'll try it out. 
One thing I'm wondering is whether I should still synchronize the `updateFX` method, or that the usage of `AtomicReference<Node>` will handle it enough.

Comment: Is `weather` even accessed from a thread other than the FX Application Thread? It's not even clear you need an `AtomicReference` for it: it's inherently single threaded.